# Why is my local dataset not loading in the kendoui grid?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a simple data source that I'm trying to load into a kendoui grid and it does not show - what am I doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var hisGrid = $("#hisGrid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        data: hisDS,
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "ID",
                fields: {
                    HIS_DT: {
                        type: "string",
                        editable: false
                    },
                    HIS_VAL: {
                        type: "string",
                        editable: false
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        pageSize: 10
    },
    height: 500,
    scrollable: true,
    sortable: true,
    selectable: true,
    columns: [{
        field: "HIS_DT",
        title: "Date/Time",
        width: 10
    }, {
        field: "HIS_VAL",
        title: "History",
        width: 5
    }]
}).data("kendoGrid");
```

});

Here's [a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/atlterry/5mFsG/25/) to the example

Would appreciate a fresh pair of eyes!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a problem with jQuery version. If you include jQuery 1.8.3 it works fine.

But as recommendation, try using the one distributed with KendoUI so you make sure that they are compatible.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.2.710/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.2.710/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.2.710/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.2.710/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
```

Fixed version here : http://jsfiddle.net/5mFsG/27/